# Android 2D Engine

Tags: android, 2d

I've been looking over a bunch of 2D Engines for Android development and I'm finding it fairly difficult to decide between all of the options. Many of the engines are no longer being developed and not all of them offer the same features.

The game I am developing will require fairly standard functionality:

- Drag and Drop
- Graphics Commands Optimized to Handle Low Sprite Count (~20)
- Sounds/Music

Taking into account that I won't be creating a super-complex game and that I'm hoping to avoid a lot of the typical hassle with creating a GUI in Java, what plug-in would satisfy my needs in a simple and optimized fashion. So far I have looked into a group of engines including cocos2D, Angle, and various others.

The engine can either be under development or not, so long as it is a complete project.

Sorry if there are any grammar errors or any confusion, I'm up rather late after setting everything up/doing the research.

Many thanks in advance,

Justian M.