# Android 2D platform game

Tags: android, 2d

I want to create a game similar like this for Android. I want to develop it fast and spend the time in creating the scenarios and the the story. Is there a good engine to create something like this?

http://www.adamatomic.com/canabalt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

http://www.andengine.org/ is exactly what you need

Comment: And what would you use to create the world map? I readed that a lot of games uses tile maps, but don't know if andengine supports it

Comment: I expect you'll discover the answer when you read the documention?

Answer (score 2):

See this: [Android 2D Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436993/android-2d-engine)

or this: http://www.andengine.org/